# Vite Uncaught TypeError when using Library that requires @emotion/styled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, emotion, material-react-table

I am currently using Vite to run some micro frontends;

I am using the following versions required to use *material-react-table* (1.15.1 latest stable version) :

> ```
> "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
> "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
> "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.15",
> "@mui/material": "^5.14.15",
> ```

```
"vite": "^4.4.5"
```

When I try to run the project in Dev it works, but if I build it and run it in preview I get the following error :

```
createSvgIcon-ddfc5f24.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: St is not a function
```

The error appears to be caused by @emotion/styled at:

```
const St = await ie("@emotion/styled");
function $t(e, t) {
    return St(e, t)
}
```

All the different micro-frontends have the needed packages instaled an shared in the vite config.

I tried to use older version of @emotion/styled but got other errors.
I also tried setting jsxImportSource with "@emotion/react" in the Vite defineConfig (and compilerOptions, also configured the @emotion/babel-plugin but got the same error everytime.

Any suggestions ?